# Cordova não consigo ultrapassar “Android target: not installed”

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou a tentar utilizar o Cordova pela primeira vez mas nao estou a conseguir.

Já vi as directorias o ficheiro AndroidManifest.xml e o project.properties

No Android Studio já instalei os SDK Android para as plataformas 14, 16 e da  20 à 27.

Não sei o que fazer mais...

Este é o dá:

```
C:\Android\Cordova\hello>cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annota
tion/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(Sc
hemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHa
ndler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinCla
ssLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(C
lassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\
gradle
(node:6696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements
 check failed
    at C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27

    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
```

[image: Android Studio SDK]

[image: Pasta SDK 25]

[image: Pasta SDK 27]

ao adicionar o android:

[image: cordova platform add android@7.0.0]

*AndroidManifest.xml alterado apos "cordova platform add android@7.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Creio que não adicionou via `cordova` no seu projeto especifico.

Primeiro verifique se o Cordova está atualizado, execute o seguinte comando:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

> Se for linux/mac:
>
> ```
> sudo npm update -g cordova
> ```

Navegue via CMD para a pasta, assim:

```
cd C:\Android\Cordova\hello
cordova platform add android
```

Pode demorar um pouco.

Se quer adicionar uma versão especifica do android, por exemplo, no seu androidmanifest.xml o targetSDK é 25:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
```

Então é necessário o android 7.1, faça isto:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

Se for 7.1.1 como na imagem que postou:

[image: android sdk manager]

Faça assim:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.1.1
```

Documentação: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#add-platforms

---

### Suporte do cordova

Conforme o blog a ultima postagem sobre android https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/26/cordova-android-7.1.0.html por enquanto o cordova suporte para o Android 7.1.0, mas não houve updates para suporte do 7.1.1 (até o momento 20/03/2018).

Então a sugestão é usar uma versão mais antiga para o `targetSdk`, editando no `androidmanifest.xml` para:

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24"/>
```

Assim irá usar o Android 7.0 como target, então no projeto execute:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Ou:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```

Quando a versão 7.1.1 estiver disponivel no cordova basta editar novamente e colocar 25.

Comment: nao ja adicionei o android

Comment: C:\Android\Cordova\hello>cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 7.0.0
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0

Comment: @JulioMarcelo como esta o seu androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: C:\Android\Cordova\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

Comment: @JulioMarcelo SDK 25 (seu target) é para Android 7.1 e não 7.0... a provavelmente vc não instalou o Android 7.1, ou o seu cordova esta desatualizado .... Tente remover o android `cordova platform remove android` e depois adicionar a versão especifica para o 25 com este comando: `cordova platform add android@7.1.0`

Comment: O erro é o mesmo...

Comment: @JulioMarcelo verificou se o SDK 25 esta devidamente instalado no SDK Manager ou não? Verifica isso e então roda os comandos `cordova platform remove android` `cordova platform add android@7.1.0` novamente.

Comment: @JulioMarcelo tente 7.1.1, assim: `cordova platform remove android` `cordova platform add android@7.1.1`

Comment: Quando tento adicionar a 7.1.1 da erro

Comment: @JulioMarcelo "dá erro" é generalizar, mas que erro afinal? Dê detalhes

Comment: (node:7428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plat form cordova-android@7.1.1

Comment: @JulioMarcelo editei a resposta, leia a parte escrita Suporte Cordova: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285337/3635 --- depois de mudar o androidmanifest não esqueça de executar os comando para usar a versão 7.0.0 (api level 24)

Comment: tambem nao deu já adicionei a imagem

Comment: eu coloquei a imagem em cima com o que fiz, fiz o remove depois fiz o add, depois mudei o manifest e no fim fiz o requirements e o erro esta na imagem no meu post inicial, tambem ja mudei o target=android-24 no project.properties

Comment: Está resolvido. Eu tinha o java jdk-9.0.4 instalado, instalei o jdk1.8.0_162 e redireccionei a java_home para lá. Para já esta tudo a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Já Funciona.

Tinha o Java JDK 9.0.4 Instalado e era esse o problema.

Instalei o Java JDK 8u162, mudei a variável JAVA_HOME para a nova JDK e já está.